# Magento distinct(true) clause ignored

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Using the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')
    ->getCollection()
    ->distinct(true)
    ->addFieldToSelect('brand')
    ->load();
```

I've found the distinct is being ignored in 1.4.2, exactly the same code in 1.8.1 is working as I would expect (returning a single entry for each brand).

**1.4.2 result:**

```
"Ace"
"Ace"
```

**1.8.1 result:**

```
"Ace"
```

For myself I notice that 1.4.2 is returning an array of all fields from the model for each object , rather than just the one specified in the select (brand) as 1.8.1 does. I think this is what's causing the problem the distinct is included in the SELECT on both versions - in fact the SELECT statements are identical across versions.

Is there a way to get a distinct result for a single field in older versions of Magento?

**EDIT**

Based on the discussion below with liyakat my final solution was:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')
    ->getCollection()
    ->distinct(true)
    ->addFieldToSelect('brand')
    ->setOrder('brand', 'ASC');

$collection->getSelect()->group('brand');
$collection->load();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this function to get select statement of collection. and i am sure you will get result.

```
   $collection = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')
        ->getCollection()    
        ->addFieldToSelect('brand')
        ->load();

   $collection->getSelect()->columns(
    array('asbrand' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
        "distinct(brand)")
        )
    );
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work. I still see the same result e.g. the same brand appearing multiple times in the results.

Comment: Will please print this colleection like 
`echo $collection->getSelect()` so that will print query. or remove addfiled to select may be work for u

Comment: `SELECT main_table.*, distinct(brand) AS asbrand FROM custom_custom AS main_table string(3)`, this isn't much different from what i was getting before. Removing the addFieldToSelect also doesn't make a difference to the result, I still see multiple entries for the same brand

Comment: try group by name so that will comes with only one record.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write it like this

```
... $collection->getSelect()->group('product_id')->distinct(true);
```

Shorten up the code a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

While adding the join make sure blank array is passed in the third parameter (only if you are adding a join).

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    'sales_order_item',
    'sales_order_item.order_id = main_table.order_id',
    []
);
```

After that add the following to apply **DISTINCT**

```
$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```